# AMI Bios long repeating beeps on startup

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, bios

I decided to give my PC a clean this morning. This included taking the heatsink off the processor to give the fan a clean (it looks like [this](http://www.pcstats.com/articleimages/201206/install1155_hsf.jpg) if it helps).

When I turned the PC on again I got a **repeating, long, high pitched beep** (no distinct number of beeps).

I'm not sure about exact models/numbers but it's a Foxconn motherboard with an AMI Bios chip. I've had a look at AMI beep codes but nowhere mentions the beep I'm getting.

I thought I may have ruined the thermal paste so I'm going to get some more. I've also tried with nothing plugged in in the back (keyboards/mice etc. Still have everything internal plugged in) but I get the same problem.

**Is this beep code something standard?**

**Note**: I'm not at home right now so I can't find model numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the code is standard. Those beeps can indicate RAM problems.

You most likely have dust on your RAM contacts.

Remove the RAM modules, clean-up the contacts well, put them back and everything should work again.

Comment: I'll check it out when I get home today. Cheers for the info

Comment: Cleaned the contacts. It was still beeping the first time I turned it on but the second time it was fine

Comment: Glad it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no actual BIOS codes that are represented by a continuous beep ("long" is as close as they get, and that's very different from "continuous")

Therefore I am guessing this is a *fan failure warning*, which would be consistent with your meddling with, sorry, cleaning the fan ;)

Is the fan actually spinning?

Even if it is spinning, as you suggest, the thermal coupling may be faulty, causing the chip to instantly overheat, and initiating temperature/fan fail alarm.

Good luck!

Comment: All fans in my case seem to be functioning properly. I'll try out the suggestion from Overmind and if that doesn't work, order some thermal paste.